# Primary key and foreign key - Table entry deletion

Tags: php, laravel-5

Table: Users (For storing user login and personal info)
Primary key- ID

> "id" is using as foreign key in the tables complaints and books.
>
> My question is... How can I delete user entries in complaints and
>   books table when I want to delete a user from users table (in laravel
>   5.2)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your model you can leverage model events to achieve what you want:

```
public static function boot() {

    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($user) {

        if(!$user->books->isEmpty()) {
            foreach($user->books as $book) {
                $book->delete();
            }
        }

        if(!$user->complaints->isEmpty()) {
            foreach($user->complaints as $complaint) {
                $complaint->delete();
            }
        }

    });
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#events

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an `->onDelete('cascade')` to your foreign key (in your migration) if you generally want to delete related rows.

For further information:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#foreign-key-constraints